yocto gitsm, can't fetch
I'm upgrading my project from Honister to Langdale (Xilinx release cycle limited) and in that regard I'm experiencing problems with gitsm that I didn't have with Honister.

I have my own server for the repositories, and I use ssh to fetch.
It has no problem checking out, cloning etc. the main repo, only the
submodules fails.
My submodules are using lfs for some binary files.

The error I get is (things in square braces changed after the fact):
Smudge error: Error downloading fpga.bit ([hash]): batch request: ssh: Could not resolve hostname [mydomain.com]

It seems that the environment used by gitsm when fetching submodules/lfs is not preserved from my host computer. I've tried everything I can think of, also using git instead of gitsm, but that has the same problem.
Any ideas on how to resolve this without upgrading to a later yocto release (Xilinx is unfortunately not following the release schedule of Yocto)?

I found out that this is a bug in langdale's gitsm. I back ported the one from the current release, and it now works.
This seems to be the patch that rectifies the problem: https://patchwork.yoctoproject.org/project/bitbake/patch/20230819001011.3226247-1-rs@ti.com/#12841
I hope this might be useful for others, as there seems to be next to no info online about this issue with lfs and gitsm.
